Кнопки, видимые только для определённых пользователей, Bitrix24 api, php
Задача такая - приходит сообщение с указанием Данных

Алексей Алексеев | Ожидание Бюджет НДС | 123 123 | 123123 | СБП 

Для этого сообщения нужно добавить кнопку "Платёж поступил", после нажатия по которой приходит другое сообщение

Алексей Жуков | Бюджет НДС | 123 123 | 123123 | СБП 
ПЛАТЁЖ ПОСТУПИЛ

Это я сделал, но единственная нерешенная проблема - отображение кнопки... Кнопка должна показываться только тому человеку, кто выполнил запрос
$user_id = $_REQUEST['data']['USER']['ID']. Помогите, пожалуйста, вот что уже готово: 
require_once(dirname(__DIR__, 3) . "/helpers/BRestLeads.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__, 3) . "/helpers/BRestMessageSender.php");



$helpers_leads = new BRestLeads();
$helpers_messages = new BRestMessageSender();

// $helpers_leads->debug($_REQUEST);

if (!$_REQUEST || !$_REQUEST['message']) {
    echo "EMPTY REQUEST";
    $helpers_leads->debug(['msg' => 'request is empty!']);
    return;
}
$user_id = $_REQUEST['data']['USER']['ID'] ?? false;
$user_bitrix_id = $_REQUEST['user_bitrix_id'] ?? false;
$name_of_org = $_REQUEST['name_of_org'] ?? false;
$chat_id = 'chat49286';

$allowed_user_ids = [
    712,
    27,
    442,
];

if ($name_of_org == 'СБП')
    $allowed_user_ids[] = $allowed_user_id;

if (in_array($user_id, $allowed_user_ids)) {

    $keyboard = array();
    $data_params = [
        'user_bitrix_id' => $user_bitrix_id,
        'message' => $_REQUEST['message'],
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'name_of_org' => $name_of_org,
    ];

    $keyboard[] = array(
        "TEXT" => 'Платеж поступил',
        "COMMAND" => "confirmPaymentMessage", // handle.php в этой же папке
        "COMMAND_PARAMS" => json_encode($data_params),
    );

    $send_message_args = array(
        "BOT_ID" => '934',
        'DIALOG_ID' => $chat_id,
        'MESSAGE' => $_REQUEST['message'],
        "KEYBOARD" => $keyboard,
    );
    
} else {

    $send_message_args = array(
        "BOT_ID" => '934',
        'DIALOG_ID' => $chat_id,
        'MESSAGE' => $_REQUEST['message'],
    );

}

$send_result = $helpers_messages->send_private_message($send_message_args);

// $helpers_leads->debug(['msg' => 'send_result', 'result' => $send_result, 'request' => $_REQUEST]);

file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/requestlog.txt', print_r([
    'msg' => 'Запрос',
    'result' => $_REQUEST,
], true), FILE_APPEND);

echo "OK";```

